Apollo Upgrade to 4.0.0 cannot find schema.graphqls
I'm updating my app to use Apollo 4.0.0 (from 3.8.2). When building, I get this error:

No schema found. Apollo needs a .graphqls or a .json schema.

There is most definitely a file called schema.graphqls that was working fine in 3.8.2.
I can't find any documentation or other resources to understand why this build time error is being thrown.

In general this should work. Would you mind sharing your gradle configuration as well as the structure of your project (i.e. where is your schema.graphqls ifile n the hierarchy?).
